# Задача по поиску определенного куска html-кода по заданным тегам с помощью Python и BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup, теги

Задача следующая:
В файле https://...task_7_7_1%28New-York%29.html есть несколько таблиц, у которых атрибут class равен wikitable collapsible collapsed.
Я зашла в этот файл и сохранила его html-код как текстовый файл. Вот ссылка на него:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FDY6QDdxz3ZreVCxUKCo1SqXq26KfmMi/view?usp=sharing

Вам необходимо найти вторую (при нумерации с единицы) такую таблицу и просто напечатать тег из BeautifiulSoup для этой таблицы (должен выводить html-код, начинающийся с тега `<table>` и заканчивающийся `</table>`). Этот текст необходимо сдать в качестве ответа.

Для решения этой задачи полезно использовать аргумент attrs в методе find_all или другом аналогичном методе. В качестве параметра attrs принимает словарь, где ключом является название атрибута, а значением - значение атрибута.
Я написала следующий код, который, на мой взгляд, полностью соответствует условиям задачи и выдает нужный результат:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = open('test3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tableIn = []

for tag in soup.find_all('table', attrs={"class": "wikitable collapsible collapsed"}):
        tableIn.append(tag)
print(tableIn[1])
```

Однако, тестирующая система не принимает ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 0):

при выполнении задания выявлена проблема при принятии ответа - так система не принимает (не распознает диактрические знаки пробела).
[image: кусок текста вывода с диактрическим пробелом]
после замены диактрического пробела на обычный проблема решается и ответ на задание принимается